# Create a Nested List along with Core Data app using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui-list

I would like to a nested list like App Reminder app

[image: App Reminder app preview]

I have created a two entities: List and SubList. I saved the data into database but I'm not able to show the data in a nested list. How can i fetch the data from the entity and show it as nested list exactly like app reminder app?

```
List
 title:String
 timestamp:Date()
 Relation : listToSubListRelation
Sublist
 title:String
 timestamp:Date()
 Relation : SubListToListRelation
```

Core Data Entities

```
@FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ List.title, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default) 
    private var items: FetchedList<List>
```

Comment: What have you tried? A MINIMUM reproducible product will get you better answers. Something that we can copy and paste to reproduce your UI. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You _don't_ fetch the data, you access it via listToSubListRelation which is a proper on List just like any other property.